# how to override a css of sonata admin bundle in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

i want to override a css file i.e reside in sonata-project/admin-bundle/Sonata/AdminBundle/Resources/public/bootstrap/css path of sonata admin bundle project.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way you can you override the css files of sonata admin but remember this will override the   block of `stylesheets` but still you can call the `stylesheets` of parent block by calling `{{ parent() }}`

```
{% block stylesheets %}
   /* this will override the parent block you can define here your css files*/
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('cssfilepath.css') }}"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    /*this will extend the parent block */
    {{ parent() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('cssfilepath.css') }}"/>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: that i kn....but i want to override a particular css file. what you said was the another way of doing it.

Comment: i created a folder in app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/public/bootstrap/css/ and then i execute  a php app/console assets:install web/. That how we override a templates. Can we override a css files also??

Comment: other way override the classes with new styles in your stylesheet

Answer (score 4):

I used the answer of M Khalid Junaid that is working like a charm. Here some facts I missed while implementing this.

Update your `config.yml` like this:

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        list: AppBundle::Admin/list.html.twig
```

The `src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Admin/list.html.twig` then can look like this:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <style type="text/css">
        * {

        }
    </style>

    <!-- and/or -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('cssfilepath.css') }}"/>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: thanks for this, i was getting a bit confused before but this helped me more than you'll know :)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to remove/add stylesheets in Sonata Admin Bundle within configuration file without handling template files:

```
sonata_admin:
    assets:
        remove_stylesheets:
            - bundles/sonataadmin/css/old.css # path to vendors css-file to remove
        extra_stylesheets:
            - build/admin/css/new.css # your css-file to add
```

Considered above options are listed in Sonata Admin Bundle [CONFIGURATION](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/configuration.html) in [FULL CONFIGURATION OPTIONS](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/configuration.html#full-configuration-options) section.