# Time picker (no date) in a Sonata-admin form

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm upgrading a Symfony project's Sonata Admin usage, from Sonata-Admin 2.2 to 2.3, as part of upgrading the overall project to Symfony 2.7.

We have a number of 'time' fields (that is, defined in Doctrine as "time", with no meaningful date component.)

In Sonata-Admin 2.2 the FormMapper definition was simple:

```
$formMapper
   ->tab('tab.general')
   ->add('start', null, array('label' => 'label.start')
   ->end()
```

and that gave the layout of "half-form-width" Hour and Minute selection boxes, side by side, in the form:

[image]

But Sonata-Admin 2.3 is showing them over two full lines:

[image]

which is not so nice or useable.

So, what should I be setting to get the same rendering?

I've tried using the 'sonata_type_datetime_picker' but that is really insistent on displaying a date. These fields do not have a date. There seems to be no equivalent for just picking the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue and solved it by adding my own CSS file for overrides.

1) Add class to your form field

```
->add('start', 'time', array(
    'attr' => array('class' => 'fixed-time')
))
```

2) Create a new CSS file in your bundle under *Resources/public/css/override.css* with overrides by *fixed-time* class

For example:

```
.fixed-time .select2-container {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

3) Then somewhere in your bundle (Resources/views) create a new template called standard_layout.html.twig and override Sonata template + add newly created CSS file (remember to call parent() first, to load sonata code first).

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('bundles/yourbundle/css/override.css')}}" type="text/css" media="all"/>
{% endblock %}
```

4) Then register your standard_layout twig template into Sonata admin (in your config.yml).

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        layout: YourBundle::standard_layout.html.twig
```

**Do not forget to install new assets (assets:install) and clear cache (remove selected folder from app/cache), otherwise you will not see any change.**

Comment: thanks! This validates a work-around I eventually found, combining tips from https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2571 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828729/how-to-override-a-css-of-sonata-admin-bundle-in-symfony2