# Sonata admin form field on same line

Tags: css, forms, sonata-admin

Is there a way in configureformsfields method from admin to show field on a same line and not one below the other? A CSS class for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add CSS class with an appropriate display option to the selected field as:

```
->add('fieldname', null, [
          'attr' => ["class" => "your-custom-class"]
      ])
```

Also you can modify `.form-group` class (to make all fields inline):

```
.form-group {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you want your input to be inline with its label:

```
div.sonata-ba-field.sonata-ba-field-standard-natural {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Tutorial how to create a CSS file and load it into Sonata template could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34683732/5759314).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not seeing how this would work without javascript. The first option will only put the class on the form field, not on the container and it's the container that needs the class for them to be side-by-side. The other options will work for *all* form containers, but what if you just want to change one form field to be next to another? CSS does not have parent selectors. Is there another way that this can be accomplished without using JS/JQuery? Perhaps I'm missing something (I'm not the greatest with css).

Comment: does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

In symfony 4 you can configure it globally in the `config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml`

```
sonata_admin:
    options:
        form_type: 'horizontal'
```

Gives:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is some workaround:
 - Create custom form type to add new option to form field

```
class CustomTextType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $view->vars['parent_div_class'] = $options['parent_div_class'];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return TextType::class;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'custom_text_type';
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(
        [
            'parent_div_class' => null,
        ]
    );
}
```

- Create custom form theme that extends sonata one

> {% extends '@SonataDoctrineORMAdmin/Form/form_admin_fields.html.twig' %}
>
> {% block form_row %}
>
> {% if parent_div_class is defined and parent_div_class %}
>
> ```
>    <div class="{{ parent_div_class }}">
>        {{ parent() }}
>     </div>
> ```
>
> {% else %}
>          {{ parent() }}
>      {% endif %}
>      {% endblock %}

- Set this theme in your admin class

  $this->setFormTheme(['@Admin/form/form_theme.html.twig']);

enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

The `SonataCoreBundle` provides the `form_type` option for this.

```
# app/config/config.yml

sonata_core:
    form_type: horizontal
```